# How avoid infinity composed indexes in firestores

Tags: json, performance, google-cloud-firestore, maps, structure

I'm doing a social media and in my posts i have 'tags' (which are practical infinity, as they are more then 200), i want my users to filter both tags and date, example:

myRef.where("tag" == "tagName").orderBy('date', 'asc')

BUT... I do have infinity number of tagNames, which give me a shock and i couldn't handle.

Should i create a custom map with sections of 1m size ???
Should i create a custom ID with data on it???
How will i be able to mix data asc with these queries or mix two or more types together?

Answer (score 0):

The query you have requires an index on `tag + date`, **not** on `tagName + date`.

But if you want to keep a list of tags for each document, you'll want to store those in an array, and then use `array-contains` to check whether the document has a certain tag. To see if `tagName` exists in the array of String values `tag`, you'd query for:

```
myRef.where("tag", "array-contains", "tagName").orderBy('date', 'asc')
```

For more on this, see [Better Arrays in Cloud Firestore!](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html)